# When was this picture taken?

Tags: 20th-century, world-war-one, photography

This is a picture from my family's book & stationery store that was in Aspen, Colorado, and I'd love to get a better idea when it was taken.

[image: Ted Cooper at the Cooper Book & Stationery]

We owned the store between maybe 1905 and maybe 1945.  The calendar on the wall looks like it says July, with the 1st on a Sunday, which means it's either 1906, 1917, 1923, 1934, or 1945.  I've been trying to decipher the names on the magazines and compare against online images of covers from those times but haven't had any success.  The comic book (?) on the table (lower shelf, right side) looks like it's got a biplane on it, and with the "Victory" poster on the back wall (right side) that would suggest 1917.

In case the picture doesn't get uploaded at its full resolution, the "original" is [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RmIEDBczJNl52lBe6cNzLVJpJLYs7nXp/view?usp=sharing).

Ideas?

EDIT

I realize I did leave out one rather important piece of information.  That's my grandfather and he was born in 1883.

Comment: 2 thougts: Limit is 2MB, any chance to get an even sharper pic with more details? (Thx in advance, it's already above par for first upload!) // Any more details for shop, place, person (eg: his presumed age?) // A first guess for any answerer: this is *after* 34, based on the "tech" to be seen in that book store? 1 grammophone and 2 radios, the latter most probably not 1917 style? (For eg RCA that style seems to be at least this late: https://www.radiomuseum.org/r/rca_r71.html) That site may be in need of consultation for an answer anyway ;)

Comment: A wide variety of (pulp) magazines with ‘Western’ prominent in their title across most of that time, so no real help there. Most seem to be post-WW1 though.

Comment: The style of the pulpish covers looks later rather than earlier.  I'd guess 1930+ on that basis.

Comment: Great big "V" for victory on the back wall, perhaps WW2 era?

Comment: Also the eagle (left of the big "V"), with the very tall wings, may be a hint (before they were less tall). That looks like a specific style that I *vaguely* remember as being in the 30's, but couldn't find anything yesterday.

Comment: Looking at the "V" poster, I think it is likely "Victor" (as in RCA Victor) - if it was "Victory" then the main word would be offset to the right a bit awkwardly. I can't find an example of a Victor ad like this but I have a suspicion I've seen it before.

Comment: What cool observations on an intriguing question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that the magazine on the right of the lower level of the table (right at the very bottom of the photo) is the May 1934 issue of Flying Aces -- see [lumist.org](http://www.luminist.org/archives/PU/FLA_1934_08_L.jpg) for an image of the pulp.  Since 1934 is also one of the calendric years, this seems like a moderately good guess.  It also fits well with the general style of the pulp covers -- 20s pulps looked *very* different, but they're consistant with the 30s or 40s.

Comment: Oh, good eye on that magazine.

Comment: very nice - good catch! I think you're completely right.

Comment: Now that I've remembered to include his birth year, this answer makes even more sense. 1934-1883 = 51 years old which I think seems reasonable for his appearance.

Comment: Why not 'quote' the picture itself here? (links rot) Also: I'd find it nice if you could incorporate useful info from comments into the A. And this includes your own impression about "pulpish" mags.

Comment: @LаngLаngС  I'm not sure of the rules and rights for quoting images.  If it would be within SE rules, go ahead and edit the answer.

Comment: We're an educational & research site, to convey a scholarly argument or to convey information., we might take one pic (perhaps even cropped to match photo from QP?) for comparison & comment – if that' not fair use?

Comment: It's a good bet that the cover is out of copyright: anything published in the United States prior to 1964 would have needed to have its copyright renewed, and copyrights on time-sensitive publications such as magazines and newspapers were almost never renewed.